# Moment of inertia of a cantilever beam

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, moment, structural-beam

As part of a project, I'm calculating deflection of a cantilever beam, something like the image below where the beam bends due to a load.

[image]

To do so requires its moment of inertia, and I'm thinking of using the beam's rectangular cross section. However, all the sources I've looked at only describe moment of inertia about the x or y axes and rotating about the center of the object--not one end of the beam and the z axis as is shown with the cantilever beam.

So, would the moment of inertia in this case still be $I=\frac{1}{12}bh^3$ as is the case for all the other rectangular cross section moment formulas I've seen, or would it be different and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the $I(x)$ term in the beam deflection formula is the area moment of inertia of a *cross-section* of the beam about an axis perpendicular to the plan of the cross-section. $I(x)$ may be a function of the distance $x$ along the beam - although in your example its is not, as the cross-section of the beam is the same at all points along it.

The [perpendicular axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_axis_theorem) tells us that the area moment of inertia of a two-dimensional shape about an axis perpendicular to its plane is the sum of its moments of inertia about two perpendicular axes within its plane. For a rectangle with height $h$ and breadth $b$ this gives

$\displaystyle I_z = I_x + I_y = \frac 1 {12} bh^3 + \frac 1 {12} b^3h = \frac 1 {12} bh(h^2+b^2)$